# Async calls using K8s client

Tags: kubernetes, quarkus, mutiny, quarkus-reactive

I'm struggling to make an Async call to perform actions on Kubernetes since the client is not provided as reactive.
For example, creating a namespace

```
Namespace namespace = new NamespaceBuilder().withNewMetadata().withName(namespaceToBeCreated).endMetadata().build();
client.namespaces().createOrReplace(namespace);
```

How can I perform this request using Mutiny for example?

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to try and do this the way you propose, it needs to be handled by the client itself (there is work going on to make this happen, see [this](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/2764) for example)